# Collect time-series data and save it in sql database using TCP

Tags: c#, sql, tcp

I am trying to write an app in C# to collect some time-series data from an executive which I am running locally on my VM and write the values to a sql database every minute (preferably using TCP communication protocol). Any idea where to start? Looking for some good references if you know any. Thanks

Comment: you can find many useful libraries which will do the heavy lifting of connectiong to a SQL database. I can suggest Entity Framework

Comment: Why not just push data into a time-series pipeline?  Good examples include Keen, Snowplow, Segment, etc.

Example [link](https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-sdk-net)